# dplyr `left_join()` does not work with a character objects as the LHS variable

Tags: r, join, dplyr, left-join

**I can** join two datasets that contain two variables with different names using `dplyr::left_join(..., by = c("name1" = "name2")`.

**I want to** join using character objects, `left_join(..., by = c(nameOb1 = nameOb2)`. Oddly: this works for `by = c("name1", nameOb2)`, *but not for* `by = c(nameOb1, "name2")`.

Why is this?

Replication of my issue below. Many thanks.

#### Generate data

```
    orig <- tibble(name1 = c("a", "b", "c"),
                   n     = c(10, 20, 30))  

    tojoin <- tibble(name2 = c("a", "b", "c"),
                     pc    = c(.4, .1, .2))
```

#### Works: using character strings for the `by` arguments

```
    left_join(orig, tojoin, by = c("name1" = "name2"))

    # A tibble: 3 x 3
      name1     n    pc
      <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
    1 a        10   0.4
    2 b        20   0.1
    3 c        30   0.2
```

#### Does not work: using object as the character string for the *first* `by` argument

```
    firstname <- "name1"

    left_join(orig, tojoin, by = c(firstname = "name2"))

    # Error: `by` can't contain join column `firstname` which is missing from LHS
    # Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

#### Works: using object as the character string for the *second* `by` argument

```
    secondname <- "name2"

    left_join(orig, tojoin, by = c("name1" = secondname))

    # A tibble: 3 x 3
      name1     n    pc
      <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
    1 a        10   0.4
    2 b        20   0.1
    3 c        30   0.2
```

Packages:

dplyr 0.8.0.1

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it has to do with this: `# Note that only the key from the LHS is kept`. Now since `firstname` isn't available in LHS, you need to devise some mechanism to match it. My efforts have been futile.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but a workaround: `left_join(orig, tojoin, by = 'names<-'("name2", firstname))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hy, the 'left_join' function needs a named character vector in the by argument. In your second try:

```
firstname <- "name1"
left_join(orig, tojoin, by = c(firstname = "name2"))
```

You set the name of the character vector to `firstname` which does not work for the join. 
For solving this you can first generate a named character vector and pass it then to the by argument of the join function

```
firstname <- "name1"
join_cols = c("name2")
names(join_cols) <- firstname

dplyr::left_join(orig, tojoin, by = join_cols)
```

Comment: The question is **why** does it not work for `firstname` but works for `secondname`

Comment: My first sentence answer this question!

Comment: You set a wrong character vector. By initialize a character vector with `c(firstname = "name2")` the names of your vector entries are not the string which is set in the variable `firstname`. In your second example, you set the variable `secondname` as the vector entire, this means that in the character vector, the value is the string which is set in your `secondname` variable. You set the name of this entry with the string "name2". Hope you get the point.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Freakazoid -- that works, and I now understand why,